# How to calculate pressure change at a U bend of a rectangular duct, with a compressible fluid?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, aerodynamics, bernoulli-equation, navier-stokes

This is not homework, just a home project that I'm working on - although I'd like to get to the end result myself.

I'm familiar with Bernoulli's and Navier-stokes equations, it's just been a while and I'm struggling to find good reference material.

The project is a heat exchanger.
A compressible fluid, at 'x' °C, is forced into the duct at 'x' m/s where it enters an enclosure.
The fluid is deflected at 90° (hard 90°, not a curved bend), travels 'x' m along a heated surface of 'x' °C, and deflects at 90° again, leaving through a duct identical in size to the inlet.

I understand that if the fluid was incompressible, then the pressure wouldn't change, but as it is compressible, how do I calculate the pressure change in the enclosure/along the heated plane?

Any guidance, and reference material, would be appreciated.

Comment: One thing to note, pressure actually does drop with incompressible fluids through pipes and bends.

Comment: Why are you approximating the fluid as inviscid?